# Prove $\sup f^2 \leq [\sup f]^2$ with $f \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

## Question

Prove
$$
\sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f^2(x) \leq \left( \sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f(x) \right)^2
$$
when $f(x) \geq 0$.

## My idea

\begin{align}
f(x) &\leq \sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f(x)\\
f^2(x) &\leq [\sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f(x)]^2\\
\sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f^2(x) &\leq \sup_{x \in\mathbb R} [\sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f(x)]^2\\
&= [\sup_{x \in\mathbb R} f(x)]^2
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! You did very well!

Comment: This is correct, but for better readability I would advise against using $x$ for both the inner and outer supremum (for instance, renaming the variable in the inner sup to $y$ would improve readability).